# Posição de Texto em gráfico de pizza no ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tenho a seguinte tabela

```
Var1              Freq        Percentual
Até 50 anos       4657         2.98%
De 51 a 60 anos   32009        20.47%
De 61 a 70 anos   57368        36.68%
De 71 a 80 anos   46075        29.46%
Mais de 80 anos   16299        10.42%
```

E preciso de um gráfico de pizza que os percentuais de cada faixa etária fique na posição correta

```
graf.faixa.etaria <- ggplot(tabela.faixa.etaria, aes(x ="", y=Freq, fill=Var1)) + geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") + 
  coord_polar("y", start = 0, direction = -1) + 
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.grid=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x=element_blank(),
    legend.title = element_blank()) + 
  geom_text(data = tabela.faixa.etaria, aes(x ="", y=Freq, label = Percentual)) +
  labs(title = "Gráfico 6: Faixa de Idade dos Inativos",
       subtitle = "Fonte: Base de Dados SIGRH")
graf.faixa.etaria
```

[image: Resultado do código acima]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fiz a inclusão da função `position_stack()` dentro de `geom_text()`

```
graf.faixa.etaria <- 
  ggplot(tabela.faixa.etaria, aes(x ="", y=Freq, fill=Var1)) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") + 
  coord_polar("y", start = 0, direction = -1) + 
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.grid=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x=element_blank(),
    legend.title = element_blank()) + 
  geom_text(data = tabela.faixa.etaria, 
            aes(x ="", y=Freq, label = Percentual),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(title = "Gráfico 6: Faixa de Idade dos Inativos",
       subtitle = "Fonte: Base de Dados SIGRH")
graf.faixa.etaria
```